# common data structures vs DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, structure

The most common data structures are as far as I understand:

```
Arrays
Stacks
Queues
Linked lists
Trees
Hash Tables
Heaps
Graph Data structures
```

How about DataFrame? Is DataFrame a separate data structure or is is a mutation of some of the listed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas DataFrame docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html)

> **DataFrame** is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or SQL table, or **a dict of Series objects**.

It is basically a dict of Series objects. Now what are Series objects?

> **Series** is a one-dimensional **labeled array** capable of holding any data type (integers, strings, floating point numbers, Python objects, etc.). The axis labels are collectively referred to as the index.

These are labeled arrays

Comment: Does it mean then that DataFrame is a dictionary of labelled arrays? I wonder how to explain to a e.g. Scala or Java developer what is DataFrame?

Comment: @BlueTomato I believe "two dimensional labeled array of python objects"; with some experiment with the module this should be clear imo

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame is part of the `pandas` python data analysis library, and is comparable to a spreadsheet or an SQL table. It's not a native Python type, but a DataFrame can contain columns of different types. See [Pandas Dataframe docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)

Comment: Hi, this is clear. I know it is part of Pandas and it is similar to SQL table. However, the question is how does it compare to common Data Structures?